# JBOSS AS 7 Database internal

Tags: jboss

1 and i'm connected to intern database java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS

i want to browse the data like sql in tables etc. in the administration console of jboss 
but there is no such option in Administration menu or can someone help me on how to browse data? Or is there some other tool on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database has nothing to do with application server. First you have to find out what database server is datastore ExampleDS using. Then connect to that server. Example: if ExampleDS uses Mysql on 192.168.1.1:3306 you have to use some Mysql client (Mysql workbanch) to connect  to that server. There you can see actual tables.

Comment: yes ok i thougt there i jboss internal tool for viewing this data thanks